# Is it illegal in Germany to pretend being sentenced for committing homicide?

Tags: germany, homicide, hypothetical

People often want you to tell them a story. For me this question is overreaching and I feel uncomfortable.

So I was wondering to what extend it is legal to make up a story I am fine with.

Comment: What will you do if they believe you and spread the tale? "He told me ..."

Answer (score 4):

[§145d StGB](https://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/145d.html) makes it illegal to pretend that a crime did happen or will happen, but only if one deceives the police or a similar agency. It is also a crime to deceive about the participants of a crime.

Pretending to *have been sentenced* and presumably to have been released after serving a sentence does not quite fit that law.

Comment: Depending on the context: If you were caught shoplifting and you tell the security guard "I killed someone and served my sentence. Are you sure I didn't pay for these goods?" that might get you into trouble.